# Histogram with a logarithmic scale for the y-axis

Tags: histograms, logarithmic-scale

How can I get a histogram with a logarithmic scale only on the the y-axis?

With

```
data=RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200]

Histogram[data, {"Log", 10}, "LogCount"]
```

I get a log scaled histogram for both axis.
I'm using mathematica 7.

Comment: `Histogram[data, Automatic, "LogCount"]` works for me (Mma 9).

Comment: Or `Histogram[data, "Linear", "LogCount"]` specifies linear for the x-axis and log for the y.

Comment: It works great, thx

Comment: I voted to leave this post open. @MikeLimaOscar Please post that as an answer. This question, although simple, is well written with a clear MWE and should be answered. (If it gets closed in the meantime, please ping me.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right place for this feedback, but it's generally advised that you should avoid using a logarithmic scale when using bars. Bars are great for encoding relative size, but only when the scale is linear, e.g. where a bar that is 2x as long encodes a value that is 2x as large. If you are wanting to use a logarithmic scale, dots or horizontal lines (e.g. where the top of the bar would be) would be a less distortive solution.

Comment: @mattsoave I converted your post to a comment.  Once you have more "reputation" you will be able to comment directly.  If you wish to follow Yves' advice and make your answer complete with examples let me know and I'll un-delete it.

Answer (score 10):

The second argument to `Histogram` controls the bins, the third the counts so simply use

```
Histogram[data, Automatic, "LogCount"]
```

or as suggested by @Bill use `"Linear"` in place of `Automatic`.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
data = Flatten@{Array[1 &, 5], Array[3 &, 20], Array[2 &, 180]};

Histogram[data, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
 Ticks -> {{# + .5, #} & /@ Range[1, 3], Automatic}]
```

gives:

[image]